# Path planning to get close to an unreachable target

Tags: path-finding

I'm working on a game which has tank battles on a tiled map. If a tank is on a cell, that cell is considered unpassable in the A* algorithm, therefore, whenever an unit needs to attack another, I need to plan a path which brings the attacker into range (if range=1, then next to the target).

Currently, I use an iterative approach with increasing radius to find a path to a nearby cell and choose a cell which minimizes the A-Cell-B distance. Unfortunately, this is slow for one unit, not to mention for 50 units.

Is there a way to extract a partial path from a regular A* search data structures?

Just for reference, here is the implementation I have.

```
Set<T> closedSet = U.newHashSet();
Map<T, T> cameFrom = U.newHashMap();
final Map<T, Integer> gScore = U.newHashMap();
final Map<T, Integer> hScore = U.newHashMap();
final Map<T, Integer> fScore = U.newHashMap();
final Comparator<T> smallestF = new Comparator<T>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        int g1 = fScore.get(o1);
        int g2 = fScore.get(o2);
        return g1 < g2 ? -1 : (g1 > g2 ? 1 : 0);
    }
};
Set<T> openSet2 = U.newHashSet();
List<T> openSet = U.newArrayList();
gScore.put(initial, 0);
hScore.put(initial, estimation.invoke(initial, destination));
fScore.put(initial, gScore.get(initial) + hScore.get(initial));
openSet.add(initial);
openSet2.add(initial);
while (!openSet.isEmpty()) {
    T current = openSet.get(0);
    if (current.equals(destination)) {
        return reconstructPath(cameFrom, destination);
    }
    openSet.remove(0);
    openSet2.remove(current);
    closedSet.add(current);
    for (T loc : neighbors.invoke(current)) {
        if (!closedSet.contains(loc)) {
            int tentativeScore = gScore.get(current)
             + distance.invoke(current, loc);
            if (!openSet2.contains(loc)) {
                cameFrom.put(loc, current);
                gScore.put(loc, tentativeScore);
                hScore.put(loc, estimation.invoke(loc, destination));
                fScore.put(loc, gScore.get(loc) + hScore.get(loc));
                openSet.add(loc);
                Collections.sort(openSet, smallestF);
                openSet2.add(loc);
            } else
            if (tentativeScore < gScore.get(loc)) {
                cameFrom.put(loc, current);
                gScore.put(loc, tentativeScore);
                hScore.put(loc, estimation.invoke(loc, destination));
                fScore.put(loc, gScore.get(loc) + hScore.get(loc));
                Collections.sort(openSet, smallestF);
            }
        }
    }
}
return Collections.emptyList();
```

Comment: Before you change your algorithm too much, consider using a more appropriate openSet representation (ie a heap), and an efficient decreaseKey. Also perhaps consider whether you can decrease the density of the graph - change the problem until it becomes more amenable to solving in the amount of time you have available. What you're doing sounds reasonable

Comment: Never mind. I solved the issue by finding the minimum distance from target & source in the closed set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that seems to work (replacing the last return Collections.emptyList();):

```
    // if we get here, there was no direct path available
    // find a target location which minimizes initial-L-destination

    if (closedSet.isEmpty()) {
        return Pair.of(false, Collections.<T>emptyList());
    }
    T nearest = Collections.min(closedSet, new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            int d1 = trueDistance.invoke(destination, o1);
            int d2 = trueDistance.invoke(destination, o2);
            int c = U.compare(d1, d2);
            if (c == 0) {
                d1 = trueDistance.invoke(initial, o1);
                d2 = trueDistance.invoke(initial, o2);
                c = U.compare(d1, d2);
            }
            return c;
        }
    });
    return Pair.of(true, reconstructPath(cameFrom, nearest));
```

Where the trueDistance gives the eucleidian distance of two points. (The base algorithm uses a simpler function yielding 1000 for X-X or YY neightbor, 1414 for XY neighbor).